# Why am I unable to use few properties in Data Table class in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a table in an app using the **Data Table class**
In order to know more about this class, I was trying every property of the data table class mentioned on the flutter documentation website. A Problem is popping up when I tried to use a few properties here.

Problem: The named parameter 'dataRowColor' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'dataRowColor'.

I couldnt use these Properties:

- dataTextStyle
- headingRowColor
- headingTextstyle
- showBottomBorder
- dataRowColor

```dart
DataTable(
      dataRowColor: 
      columns: const <DataColumn>[
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Name'
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Age'
          ),
        ),
        DataColumn(
          label: Text(
            'Role'
          ),
        ),
      ],
      rows: const <DataRow>[
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
            DataCell(Text('19')),
            DataCell(Text('Student')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('Janine')),
            DataCell(Text('43')),
            DataCell(Text('Professor')),
          ],
        ),
        DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text('William')),
            DataCell(Text('27')),
            DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Could you provide some additional information? Minimum code to reproduce the problem would be good. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey @RobertSandberg , I added some info & code, please let me know if you need more info, thanks.

Comment: All checks out good (except for the missing input to dataRowColor). Check versions etc. and see if flutter doctor gives you any hints. The build cache might be off, so try with flutter clean and etc.

Comment: @RobertSandberg I tried to enter input to dataRowColor but is showing errors. I ran flutter doctor & got  the following error in the doctor summary.  [[Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses]].   Then I ran 'flutter doctor --android-licenses' & the doctor summary looks fine now. Then I ran 'flutter clean' but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

So I recently ran into these exact same issues. After upgrading to Flutter 1.22.6 everything seemed to work as expected and I was no longer getting this is not defined for this class errors.